# how to remove non text part of the image card

Tags: java, android, c++

I am making an app for extracting number from image card using sample code of android-ocr(tesseract-ocr). 
I have trained the data as per the card font. It is detecting few card if the card having unique background, but if the card having multi background (attached sample) then the number is not recognizing. 
Even if the card number little overlapping the background then also not recognition.

I tried to use the steps below, to remove the background:

1. Smoothing the cropped image using:

   GaussianBlur( crop, crop, Size(3,3), 0, 0, BORDER_DEFAULT );
            cvtColor( crop, crop, CV_RGB2GRAY );
2. Edge detection used sobel:

   crop = SobelEdgeDetect(crop);
3. Converting to bitwise not cv:

   bitwise_not(crop,crop);
4. Used adaptiveThreshold to remove shadowed kind of things:

   adaptiveThreshold(crop,crop,255,CV_ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, CV_THRESH_BINARY,75,10);

After using these steps I am getting the image (attached bar-Process`png, citi1-Process.png, citi-Process.png), which is coming bold with blank space inside the number. In this case the ocr application is not recognize the number. 
I do not know how can fill these number with bold letter.

Now the big challenge for me to remove the background from any image card with out disturbing the text part of the card. So please suggest me how can I overcome all the above issue specific how can remove the background of the image`
 I have attached few sample & output data for your reference.

Thanks & regards
Anil

Comment: Attachments fell off.

Comment: I am unable to upload the image. I getting the error message "You need at least 10 reputation to post images."